# How to set up a function dynamically without calling it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function which calls multiple functions at the same time and waits until all of them are finished. It's working as intended. It's labeled as `parallel` below

I've got an array which I want to map into a function with the param for each value in the array. However as you might imagine, the function is being called right when it's being mapped so the results are not being returned to the parallel results. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas on how I can do this & return the results to the parallel function?

Currently doing

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
r = await parallel(
    doStuff(array[0]),
    doStuff(array[1]),
    doStuff(array[2]),
    doStuff(array[3]),
    doStuff(array[4]),
  );
  if(r.err.code) return r;
```

Would like to do

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];

r = await parallel(array.map(v => doStuff(v)))
if(r.err.code) return r;
```

Parallel

```
async function waitForAll(...functions) {
  return await Promise.all(functions)
}

const parallel = async (...functions) => {
  const d = {err: {code:0,message:""},res:{}}; let r,sql,vars;

  r = await waitForAll(...functions)
  for(let i in r){ if(r[i].err.code) return r[i]; }

  d.res = r;

  return d;
}

module.exports = {
  parallel
}
```

Edit: `doStuff()` is async

Comment: Is this `await parallel(` even working ?

Comment: @brk it is. As the current implementation works & other areas of the project that use it are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `parallel` accepts any number of separate arguments, it looks like all you need to do is *spread* the result of mapping into the call. Right now you're only passing a single array as the first argument.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const r = await parallel(...array.map(v => doStuff(v)))
if(r.err.code) return r;
```

Or change `parallel`'s implementation to accept an array as a single argument

```
const parallel = async (functions) => {
```

and do

```
const r = await parallel(array.map(v => doStuff(v)))
```

Unless `doStuff` has different behavior depending on whether its second or more arguments are defined, you might be able to simplify to

```
const r = await parallel(array.map(doStuff))
```

removing the inline call.

Comment: Great insight, thank you. doStuff does have second arguments so the first solution you provided works perfectly. Thank you!